# Eclipse RCP - Shere javadocs and attached sources of dependencies among projects in workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a set of plugins for a commercial Eclipse RCP Application "FOO_APPLICATION", 
which comes with html javadocs for api plugins and without sources.

*I'm using Eclipse 4.5.2 and the target "FOO_APPLICATION" is based on an older version of Eclipse, 3.6*

Everything seems fine but I'm experiencing this annoying issue:

If I attach javadocs or sources to plugin dependecies (for eclipse standard plugins I can also attach sources, because I have also the original 3.6 sdk sources jar)
**Eclipse does not remember this setup and I have to do this again at every startup.** :(

[image]

[image]

What I'm missing here?

**But consider also this point: I'd really like to solve this problem from a wider point of view**: since I have many projects (in the same workspace) that share the same dependencies of "FOO_APPLICATION",
is there a way to setup sources or javadocs once and made them available throughout the whole workspace?

Answer (score 1):

If the sources are present in the target platform as [individual ***Source Bundles***](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_individual_source.htm), the source is automatically displayed.

As far as I know, there's nothing comparable for Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @howlger . That solves an important part of the problem (the core eclipse plugins for which I have the source bundles). For other plugins (the "FOO_APPLICATION" ones) I only have javadocs and it's strange I can't even keep them attached.

Comment: In plain Java projects, the locations of the source and Javadoc attachments are stored in the `.classpath` file at the JAR items. In Plug-in projects, `.classpath` refers to the _"required plug-ins"_ only, which are computed from the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` files and the target platform.